# I've added a second HD into my Macbook 2011 instead of CD-ROM. Is it safe to encrypt it using Finder?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, backup, upgrade, encryption

Years ago I changed my cdrom in my Macbook [for a second hard drive](http://www.macworld.com/article/2082572/advice-from-an-apple-tech-how-to-replace-the-optical-drive-in-a-unibody-macbook-pro-with-a-second-h.html), and have been using a SSD as a first drive ever since.

This HD is shown in Finder, and, clicking on it with two fingers, there's an option to encrypt it.

Since this has never been an endorsed upgrade from Apple (changing the cdrom for a HD) I've never used this encrypt option, but now I'm traveling too much because of work and I'm planning to do it if somehow I lose the macbook or it gets stolen.

Does anyone here now of any caveats of this approach? I think this is the same option if you plug an external HD in USB.

Answer (score -1):

I think I'm correct to say it's safe! As Mac OS sees it as a drive you can just use the encryption.

Other people have tested it in [Apple Support Comunnities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5644065?tstart=0) and it seems to work so far.

Comment: Also check: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5644065?tstart=0 they've done it before and works!